# Switch implementation of service by namespace in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm working on a Web API that connects to different repositories based on an `appsettings.json` key. The implementations are defined in different projects and share a same interface

I use this code to switch between them

```cs
switch (connector)
{
  case "MSSQL":
    services.AddScoped<IDocumentRepository, MSSQL.Repositories.DocumentRepository>();
    break;

  case "MySQL"
    services.AddScoped<IDocumentRepository, MySQL.Repositories.DocumentRepository>();
    break;
}
```

I'm looking for a solution not based on a `switch` or `if` statement.

Would be something like this

```
services.AddScoped<IDocumentRepository, $"{namespace}.DocumentRepository">();
```

Is this possible? Maybe using reflection?

Comment: Because you need to supply a `Type`, either as a generic argument or as a `Type` variable, I don't see how you can avoid using a switch (either switch statement, switch condition, or fancy if/else).

Comment: What is wrong with the switch?

Comment: How many data sources do you realistically have? As the saying goes, "if it ain't broken, don't fix it."

Comment: If the options are known at compile time, I'd argue that a switch or if statement is preferable over a more dynamic approach. You should only use the dynamic approach when 1. the options aren't available at compile time (meaning you have plugin assemblies that can be added to the application later on without a recompile) or 2. the list of options is big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use reflection to do this, but you lose some type safety.

```cs
services.AddScoped(
    typeof(IDocumentRepository),
    Type.GetType($"{myNamespace}.DocumentRepository"));
```

Comment: Do note that supplying '{namespace}.{typename}' only works when the requested type lives in the [currently executing assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-7.0#system-type-gettype(system-string)). Otherwise you'll have to supply it with the assembly-qualified name.

Comment: So, alternatively, you can also iterate the list of types in a specific assembly using `Assembly.GetExportedTypes()` or `Assembly.GetTypes()`.